# SQL count by n-tuples

Tags: oracle

Took me more time than I'd like to admit to figure out how count the number of n-tuples occurrences via Oracle SQL.

Lets say table TABLE :

```
| ID         | Order number| Value        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |        10   |     A     
| 2          |        10   |     B    
| 3          |        10   |     C     
| 4          |        10   |     D      
| 5          |        15   |     A      
| 6          |        15   |     B      
| 7          |        15   |     C      
| 8          |        15   |     D      
| 9          |        20   |     X      
| 10         |        20   |     Y      
| 11         |        20   |     Z      
| 12         |        30   |     M     
| 13         |        30   |     P      
| 14         |        40   |     X      
| 15         |        40   |     Y      
| 16         |        40   |     Z
```

I would like to count the number of order that share the same "Value" n-tuple occurrences. Output format is irrelevant as long as I can get the data, something like :

(A,B,C,D) = *2   // [Since Both order 10 and 20 share the same values]

(X,Y,Z) = *2

(M,P) = 1

n-tuple order is irrelevant (A,B,C,D) or (D,A,C,B) means the same.

Any tip or hint greatly appreciated.

Comment: just tell us what you want to be outputted with that sample data.

Comment: Since it is oracle, there is probably more than one way to do it and most effective way is dependent on your oracle version which you haven't mentioned. answer hint is listagg(value) and then in outer query group by.

Comment: Just to clarify - what about supersets? e.g., 10 = (A,B, C, D, E), 15 = (A, B, C, D). I assume that you'd have a count of one (A,B, C, D, E) and one (A,B, C, D)? (Under some circumstances, you might want to know there are two entries that contain (A, B, C, D), even if one or both contained other things as well).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LISTAGG()` function to gather the groups/tuples, then another `GROUP BY` to count occurrences of every group/tuple.

Assuming that `(order_number, value)` is unique, i.e. that no two rows have the same `order_number` and `value`:

```
WITH groups AS
  ( SELECT LISTAGG(value, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS value_group
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY order_number
  )
SELECT value_group,
       COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM groups
GROUP BY value_group ;
```

You could also get the order numbers that belong to each group:

```
WITH groups AS
  ( SELECT LISTAGG(value, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) 
             AS value_group,
           order_number
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY order_number
  )
SELECT value_group,
       COUNT(*) AS occurrences,
       LISTAGG(order_number, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_number) 
         AS order_numbers
FROM groups
GROUP BY value_group ;
```